# CMake: copy_directory custom command fails on macOS

Tags: macos, cmake

I have a cross-platform (Windows, Mac, iOS) CMake project that needs to copy binary resources (images, audio, text files, etc.) to the final application. I previously just added every resource to the `add_executable` command, and that worked fine until I wanted to organize everything into sub-directories.

To copy application assets while keeping the folder structure I ended up using the following custom command in the windows target:

```
add_custom_command(
  TARGET ${APP_TARGET_NAME} PRE_LINK
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory

  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${APP_ASSETS_DIR} 
  $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${APP_TARGET_NAME}>/assets
)
```

Which works quite well. The problem comes when I try to do the same thing on macOS. When I use the same `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR>` trick on macOS I get the address of the output application bundle (which is very good), so I add a `/resources` to the end of that and try to copy there, but this fails.

In XCode I get the following error:

```
PhaseScriptExecution CMake\ PreLink\ Rules /Users/someuser/Documents/Build/Test/Test.build/Debug/Test_MAC.build/Script-2CF8724D08BC49E4A13B9E75.sh
cd /Users/someuser/Documents/GitHub/Test
/bin/sh -c /Users/someuser/Documents/Build/Test/Test.build/Debug/Test_MAC.build/Script-2CF8724D08BC49E4A13B9E75.sh

/Users/someuser/Documents/Build/Test/Debug/Test_MAC.app/Contents/MacOS/Test_MAC -E copy_directory /Users/someuser/Documents/GitHub/Test/assets /Users/someuser/Documents/Build/Test/Debug/Test_MAC.app/Contents/Resources
make: *** [Test_MAC_buildpart_0] Segmentation fault: 11
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
```

Which isn't particularly helpful. I've tried `PRE_LINK` and `POST_BUILD` as well as `copy_directory` and `copy`.

Why is this failing? I haven't been able to test on iOS, but I imagine that the two would work in a similar way.

How can I copy my assets to the bundle on macOS (also iOS)?

Comment: The command shouldn't segfault, so that likely means there is a bug in the version of CMake that you are using.  What version are you running?  Use `cmake --version` to see this information.

Comment: When using CPack to build a dmg file I was facing regularly `Segmentation fault: 11` messages. It turned out that I forgot some resources to add and the underlying tool was crashing.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister The terminal has version 3.13.2, while the desktop app has 3.13.4

Comment: I tried upgrading the terminal to 3.13.4, but I'm getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

There's not much helpful documentation for framework/bundle generation with CMake on the net. Most wisdom is hidden in CMakeLists.txt files and not in CMake tutorials.

Both methods are known to work, but are a bit tricky to get right. I used them both together on a versioned framework project with CMake's `Unix Makefiles` generator.

First you add resources to your framework/bundle (mine has the same name as the project, therefore I use `${PROJECT_NAME}` throughout the following lines) **either** by adding them as arguments to `add_library`, e.g.

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${RESOURCES})
```

Then set your target properties for a framework/bundle:

```
  if(BUILD_MAC_FRAMEWORK)
    # Set the framework target properties just to make sure the relevant links inside the framework 
    # are created.  Because the default framework name differs from the project name we change the
    # output name property.
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
      FRAMEWORK TRUE
      FRAMEWORK_VERSION ${MAC_FRAMEWORK_VERSION}
      #PUBLIC_HEADER "${PUBLIC_HEADERS}" # does not work recursively
      #PRIVATE_HEADER "${PRIVATE_HEADERS}" # does not work recursively
      RESOURCE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/version.plist" # does not work recursively
      MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER org.company.sampleFramework.framework
      MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION}
      MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
      MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_INFO_PLIST "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Info.plist"
      OUTPUT_NAME ${MAC_FRAMEWORK_NAME}
    )
  endif()
```

Later set the framework path for the resource files with respect to `Resources` directory with a helper function

```
# determine which subdirectory this file (header, resource) should be installed into.
function(set_macosx_properties _removable_prefixes _install_prefix _source_files)
  foreach(_file ${_source_files})
    get_filename_component(_loc "${_file}" DIRECTORY)
    foreach(_prefix ${_removable_prefixes})
      string(REPLACE "${_prefix}" "" _loc "${_loc}")
    endforeach()
    set_source_files_properties(${_file} PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION ${_install_prefix}${_loc})
  endforeach()
endfunction()

set_macosx_properties("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include;${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include"  "Headers" "${HEADERS}")
set_macosx_properties("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/data;${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/data" "Resources" "${RESOURCES}")
```

The helper function removes the specified prefixes and replaces them with an installation prefix.

***Make sure both commands (`add_library` and `set_macosx_properties`) are called from the same directory/`CMakeLists.txt`! Different locations for the commands do not work.***

**Or** you use a call to `add_custom_command` as follows. I do not remember if other type of targets did not work, but I have always used `POST_BUILD` custom targets.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD 
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/Documentation
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink ./Versions/Current/Documentation $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/../../Documentation
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/html $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/Documentation/html)

add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD 
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/Documentation/html/${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.qch
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/html/${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.qch $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/Documentation)
```

Finally, installation is done by single command:

```
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} FRAMEWORK DESTINATION . COMPONENT development)
```

Comment: Hmm... Neither method seems to work. I even tried 'set_macosx_properties' directly on my array of resources but I couldn't get to to put the files in any kind of sub directory. The second method doesn't work because I get the same error I was getting before.

Comment: I updated the answer with the setup/install instructions for a framework. Can you check with `Unix Makefiles` generator instead of the XCode project?